# SpringBoot 2.7.4: Initialize Datasource from active profile properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

We are initializing datasource as per the active profile as below and we are providing the CONFIG_DIR as environment variable during the startup as `SET CONFIG=-DCONFIG_DIR=src\main\resources`, am wondering is there an alternative to initialize Datasource without having to provide the `CONFIG_DIR` as environment variable

```
String dbConfigFilePath = env.getProperty("CONFIG_DIR") + 
"/datasource"+propertyName+env.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") + ".properties";
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig(dbConfigFilePath);
```

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to source a string from something other than an environment variable, which is very open ended.  What are you trying to do?  How do you want to provide the config dir?

Comment: @Taylor I want to load the properties file based on the active profile provided and without having to provide CONFIG_DIR as environment variable

Comment: Like this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files ?